# What is the value of require_images

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, object

I am new to coding.
I am trying to edit a code and need to understand what is the value being allocated to require_images

```
$params = array(
    'appTaxTag'              => APP_TAX_TAG,
    'require_images'         => ( $cp_options->ad_images && $cp_options->require_images ),
    'ad_parent_posting'      => $cp_options->ad_parent_posting,);
```

Is the code ( $cp_options->ad_images && $cp_options->require_images ) checking if $cp_options->ad_images and $cp_options->require_images are both true and then setting the value of require_images as true or is it something else ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The value of require_images with be true or false if $cp_options->ad_images has a value and $cp_options->require_images has a value. Those variables don't need to necessary have plain or boolean true or false but other content.
So, in my opinion that means that require_images is a test variable to check if the other two variables already have values.
If you want to know the values of those variables you can perform a var_dump($cp_options) and see what ad_images contains and require_images.

Thank you.

Comment: Thanks ... what if one of the variable is NULL ? What would that mean ?

Comment: If it is NULL then it is false.